# Removing a charAt[i] from a String

Tags: java, string, comparison

Trying to remove all of the characters that are in String S2 from S1. Example would be: S1 = Mississippi River, S2 = is. Return would be S1 and it would be Mpp Rver.

```
public static String removeLetters(String S1, String S2){
    for(int i=0;i<S1.length();i++){
        for(int j=0;j<S2.length();j++){

            if(S2.charAt(i) == S1.charAt(j))
                S1.charAt(j) = ""; //this does not work but essentially what i want.
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried

```
String S1 = S1.removeAll
```

and

```
S1 = S1.remove
```

The problem is that remove all takes a String String param and .remove takes a char char, neither of which works. I've fought this for a day, can't get it, any help for noobz? :) thank you all greatly as always.

Comment: Start by reading the `String` javadoc.

Answer (score 2):

How about a simpler:

```
return S1.replace(S2, "");
```

Note that your example does not work: `Mississippi River` becomes `Mssippi River`.

If you actually want to remove all the `i`s and `s`s, you could use a regex:

```
return S1.replaceAll("[" + S2 + "]", "");
```

which returns `Mpp Rver` - that assumes that `s2` does not contain any regex-specific characters.

Comment: but that's not what he wants. He wants `Mpp Rver` - All the characters of `S2` removed from `S1`

Comment: OP asks to remove all chars in S2 from S1, not the string S2 from S1.

Comment: @sushain97 OK I misunderstood the question - edited.

Comment: Nice to confirm that I still remember How to Java.

Answer (score 2):

One simple approach would be something like:

```
public static String removeLetters(String source, String lettersToRemove) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();        
    for (int i = 0; i < source.length(); i++) {
        if (lettersToRemove.indexOf(source.charAt(i)) == -1) {
            builder.append(source.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Or:

```
public static String removeLetters(String source, String lettersToRemove) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lettersToRemove.length(); i++) {
        source = source.replace(lettersToRemove.substring(i, i + 1), "");
    }
    return source;
}
```

While the approaches using regular expressions will work in *many* cases, you'd need a bit more work to make them robust against things like "-" within `lettersToRemove`. It really depends on your requirements. (As noted in Sabuj's answer, `Pattern.quote` may well be enough here... but I'd want to validate that for myself with a few weird cases.)

Comment: Second code snippet fails to remove both i and s if letters to remove is equal to is.

Comment: @staticx: That's the "joy" of writing in both C# and Java - I know that `substring` takes a count in one platform and an end index in the other, but I sometimes get them the wrong way round...

Comment: Yea, I had to go check substring definition myself to see if I was missing something because it looked odd

Answer (score 1):

Use this one with [`Pattern.quote()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) to deal with regex special characters and treat `S2` as a literal pattern.

```
String S1 = "Mississippi River";
String S2 = "is";
S1 = S1.replaceAll("["+Pattern.quote(S2)+"]+", "");
System.out.println(S1);
```

Outputs:

```
Mpp Rver
```

Comment: That's not going to do well if the replacement string contains things like dashes though...

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, you are right. that's why I mentioned special characters in my answer.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't spotted that. I think I'd still rather use a more general approach - I view this as a bit like concatenating SQL parameters :)

Comment: `Pattern.quote()` will deal with the special character problem, right?

Comment: I *suspect* so. It looks like the behaviour of that may have changed anyway in Java 8, to use `\Q` and `\E`. I'd need to look in more detail to check.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression to remove all letters in S1 that are in S2.

```
public static String removeLetters(String S1, String S2){
    return S1.replaceAll("[" + S2 + "]", "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why this:

```
S1.charAt(j) = ""; //this does not work but essentially what i want.
```

doesn't work:  (1) You can't use a function call as the left side of an assignment; (2) even if you could, it wouldn't make sense here because `charAt()` returns a `char` and you can't assign a `char` to a `String`; (3) `String`s are immutable, so you can't just change one character of `S1` anyway.  You have to create a new string and assign `S1` to it.  [Also (4): `j` goes from 0 to `S2.length()`, not `S1.length()`, so that implies that `j` should be used as an index into `S2`, not `S1`.]

Using `replaceAll` as other answers have suggested is simplest.  If you're not allowed to, you can build up a new string with the characters you *do* want instead of removing the ones you don't want (for example, using `StringBuilder`; see Jon Skeet's answer).

Or you can use `substring` to remove a character from a string, by computing the substrings before and after the character and concatenating them.  To remove the `i`'th character of `S1` (the one at `S1.charAt(i)`), you can say

```
S1 = S1.substring(0, i) + S1.substring(i + 1);
```

The first `substring` is the characters of `S1` up to, but not including, `(i)`; the second one is the characters starting at the `i+1`'th character up to the end of the string.

However, you can't put this in your loop without other changes.  The reason is that you have an index that goes through the characters of `S1`, but you have just changed `S1` so that many of the indexes are different.  You can make this work by making the index go backward through the string, or by making sure `i` is not incremented if you remove a character.  I'll let you study this further and work out the details.

Answer (score -1):

Try Regex:

```
String pattern = "[" + S2 + "]"; // will take all chars from S2 to create a pattern.
String result = S1.replaceAll(S2,""); //will replace any char from S2.
```

Answer (score -2):

The String class is immutable, so that once it is created a String object cannot be changed.

Comment: To downvoters, get your facts right.. 

Strings are constant; their values cannot be changed after they are created. String buffers support mutable strings. Because String objects are immutable they can be shared...

The above sentences are not mine. its from oracle docs. Go and read some books.. I am even posting the link here for your reference

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html